# Changing the convention of positive and negative charge holders in an atom

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, conventions

Would there be any specific change in the physical/chemical laws if one day we changed the convention that electrons are negatively charged to the one that electrons are positively charged and vice versa for the holes?

Comment: Do you mean just changing the *convention* that the electron charge is defined as negative rather than positive, or do you mean what would change if we could flip the actual electron charge into the opposite charge (i.e. turning all matter into anti-matter)?

Comment: I think both questions are interesting!